# How can I set a background image for a UILabel and adjust its alpha without changing the transparency of the text?

Tags: iphone, uikit, ios

How can I create a `UILabel` with a background image and adjust the transparency (alpha channel) of the background image without changing the transparency of the text?

If there's no easy way to accomplish this within the `UILabel` object by itself, what about creating a custom `UIView` object that's composed of a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`, which would allow me to adjust the alpha channel of the image independently of the `UILabel`'s alpha channel? Is that more complicated than it needs to be?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Comment: Are you using [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myBackground"]] as the background of your label? Do you need the setting of the transparency to happen at runtime, or can you use PNG alpha channel transparency?

Comment: Hi Gregln, yes, I'm using colorWithPatternImage and I need the transparency to happen at runtime.

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to apply transparency to an image used with colorWithPatternImage. I suppose you could redraw the image into a graphics context using UIImage's drawInRect:blendMode:alpha: and then grab the result into a new UIImage that is used with colorWithPatternImage, but I've never tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google codesearch for UIImage, alpha and CGImageRef doesn't turn anything that does exactly what you need, but lots of related code (see for example [this](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#tAGmm6dl1nA/trunk/itemisApp/Library/UIImage/UIImage%2BAlpha.m&q=CGImageRef%20CGImage%20alpha%20uiimage&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc)). The way I would do follows the same pattern, getting a CGImageRef from your image, drawing it with a composition mode with your transparency, and getting back a UIImage from that using `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:]`.